# Import error missing module enum

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a python file, but I keep getting a ImportError.

My set up is I have a project with the following path:

`/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX`

within 'projectX' I have a folder called 'components' which contains two python files titled 'py_file' and '**init**'.

`/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX/components`

At the top of 'py_file', I'm importing a namedTuple that is defined in '**init**'

`from components import some_tuple`

When I run `python py_file.py run` I get `ImportError: No module named components`

I tried changing the `PYTHONPATH` to the project root and running the file again, but then I get this error `ImportError: No module named enum`.

`PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX
export PYTHONPATH`

after exporting the `PYTHONPATH`, every time I try to open a python shell I get the enum import error.

Answer (score 0):

`enum` was added in Python version 3.4.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

You are most likely running too old Python.

Check with `python -v`

Comment: I do have enum34 installed and the documentation says it is backported for python 2.7

Comment: I upgraded to python 3.4, now I'm getting `ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'`

Comment: This seems to be an organizational problem with your project as somebody is not maintaining dependencies correctly for the project.  There is no point to help you forward as you would be asking for the next unknown dependency next. I suggest you read this article http://blog.ziade.org/2013/04/13/declaring-dependencies-in-python/ and Python documentation regarding packaging http://packaging.python.org/ and establish a version maintenance and pindown policy for your project.

Comment: we're maintaining a requirements.txt file.  I created a new virtualenv with the dependencies listed in the requirements.txt installed.  I'm assuming that should clear any dependency issues.  The fact that it can't find the name of the directory that the file I'm trying to run is contained in makes me think its something else.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by adding these line at the top of my file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from components import some_tuple
```

I originally only had `from components import some_tuple`